# Javers Mongo Multitenancy Issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, javers

My Spring boot application has a multitenancy architecture and I'm using Javers to audit some data models.

The issue I'm facing is that Javers is not able to resolve the database based on my MongoDatabaseFactory implementation.

So far I've tried creating a Javers Configuration Bean which looks like this:

```html
@Component
public class JaversMongoConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    CachedMongoClients cachedMongoClients;


    @SneakyThrows
    public Javers javers() {
        MongoRepository javersMongoRepository =
                new MongoRepository(cachedMongoClients.getMongoDatabaseForCurrentContext());  // Custom method to fetch the MongoDataBase based on current TenantContext

        return JaversBuilder.javers()
                .registerJaversRepository(javersMongoRepository)
                .build();
    }
}
```

This isn't working as during project build time, Javers instantiates the connection to the default database and dynamically doesn't switch to the tenant database as intended during run time.

Hence, all my audit logs are getting saved at the default database and not in tenant database.

**Note: I'm using Javers Spring Boot Mongo starter and Javers Mongo Persistence Maven dependencies.**

Answer (score 0):

In Javers there is no integration with Spring multitenancy. Javers is open source, you are encouraged to contribute https://github.com/javers/javers/